# Java - Extract string from pattern

Tags: java, regex

Given some strings that look like this:

```
(((((((((((((4)+13)*5)/1)+7)+12)*3)-6)-11)+9)*2)/8)-10)
(((((((((((((4)+13)*6)/1)+5)+12)*2)-7)-11)+8)*3)/9)-10)
(((((((((((((4)+13)*6)/1)+7)+12)*2)-8)-11)+5)*3)/9)-10)
```

(btw, they are solutions for a puzzle which I write a program for :) )

They all share this pattern

```
"(((((((((((((.)+13)*.)/.)+.)+12)*.)-.)-11)+.)*.)/.)-10)"
```

For 1 solution : How can I get the values with this given pattern?
So for the first solution I will get an collection,list,array (doesn't matter) like this:

```
[4,5,1,7,3,6,9,2,8]
```

Comment: Google "java regular expressions capturing groups".

Comment: Or, if all the dots are supposed to be single digit numbers, just index into the string, grabbing the 12th, 19th, 22nd, and so on characters...

Comment: Split using regex `"\\D+"` (and remove/ignore the empty element at the beginning)

Comment: If it's not a requirement to use regexes, you could try to use a Scanner too.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please consider accepting it (green checkmark to the left).

Answer (score 3):

You've done most of the work actually by providing the pattern. All you need to do is use capturing groups where the `.` are (and escape the rest).

I put your inputs in a `String` array and got the results into a `List` of integers (as you said, you can change it to something else). As for the pattern, you want to capture the dots; this is done by surrounding them with `(` and `)`. The problem in your case is that the whole string is full of them, so we need to quote / escape them out (meaning, tell the regex compiler that we mean the literal / character `(` and `)`). This can be done by putting the part we want to escape between `\Q` and `\E`.

The code below shows a coherent (though maybe not effective) way to do this. Just be careful with using the right amount of `\` in the right places:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] inputs = new String[3];
        inputs[0] = "(((((((((((((4)+13)*5)/1)+7)+12)*3)-6)-11)+9)*2)/8)-10)";
        inputs[1] = "(((((((((((((4)+13)*6)/1)+5)+12)*2)-7)-11)+8)*3)/9)-10)";
        inputs[2] = "(((((((((((((4)+13)*6)/1)+7)+12)*2)-8)-11)+5)*3)/9)-10)";

        List<Integer> results;

        String pattern = "(((((((((((((.)+13)*.)/.)+.)+12)*.)-.)-11)+.)*.)/.)-10)"; // Copy-paste from your question.
        pattern = pattern.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\E(.)\\\\Q");
        pattern = "\\Q" + pattern;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m;

        for (String input : inputs) {
            m = p.matcher(input);
            results = new ArrayList<>();
            if (m.matches()) {
                for (int i = 1; i < m.groupCount() + 1; i++) {
                    results.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(i)));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(results);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 1, 7, 3, 6, 9, 2, 8]
[4, 6, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 3, 9]
[4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 5, 3, 9]
```

#### Notes:

- You are using a single `.`, which means

  > Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

  So if you have a number there which is not a single digit or a single character which is not a number (digit), something will go wrong either in the `matches` or `parseInt`. Consider `\\d` to signify a single digit or `\\d+` for a number instead.
- See [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more info on regex in Java.

Comment: @Domien If this answer solved your question, please consider accepting it (green checkmark to the left).